# Insert is abnormal after rename collection name

Tags: arangodb

My operations is following:

1. Use insert script to insert 1 million documents in 'Node' collection. ArangoDB consumed 30MB memory.
2. Rename 'Node' collection to "Node_temp".
3. Use insert script to insert 100 documents in 'Node' collection. It is successful.

After these operations I find a problem. In Admin webUi(ArangoDB), it's no response for a long time when I clicked 'Node' for find documents in 'Collections' Page. ArangoDB consumed 900MB memory. After a long time (more than 5 minutes), the web pages is opened, it displayed there are 1 million documents in 'Node' collection. I think it maybe something wrong in rename operations.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this and did not encounter any problems. Renaming works, inserting into collection "Node" fails as expected, and I did not encounter long loading times when opening collection "Node_temp" ("Node" is already gone because of renaming). I used ArangoDB 2.2.4 and the ArangoShell as a client. My test script was: `db._drop("Node_temp"); db._drop("Node"); db._create("Node"); for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) db.Node.save({ value: i }); c.rename("Node_temp"); for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) db.Node.save({ value:i });`

Comment: I think your operations is different. I use perl and ArangoDB 2.2.4, but I think the result should be the same. After "c.rename("Node_temp");" , you execute db._create("Node"); and then "for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) db.Node.save({ value:i });". at the last, you opening collection "Node". You'll find the problem.

Comment: Think I got it, though it was really hard to figure out as the issue wasn't fully reproducible. What seemed to happen is that a server-side cache for collection names wasn't always invalidated for all threads. This may have caused some operations to point to the "old" collection "Node_temp" (the one that was originally named "Node"), but only in some cases and under some circumstances. This has also confused the web interface, which issued an very expensive select query on the "Node_temp" collection which was intended to run on the much smaller "Node" collection.

Comment: A fix for this has been committed in 2.2 and devel, and will be included in release 2.2.5.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's not a big problem. In production, it's seldom operation like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in version 2.2.5. Thanks for pointing this out!